# C# don't wait task to finish, but result needed

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Simply I want to make an external call to external api which has `SenMessageAsync(string message)` method and i need to return my client `Ok()` without waiting it to finish. But on the backend side I need to response of `SendMessageAsync()` method for continue some process. I mean somehow I need to await it.

Example

```
try
{
    //...
    var response = await SendMessageAsync("test"); //dont wait the response, return Ok()
    //do something with response
}
catch(MyException ex)
{
    //Log
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Log
}
```

Update:

I am updating with one solution I found. `Task.Run()` (which called fire and forget). Maybe it helps someone. Thanks for answers.

**Solution 1:**

```
_ = Task.Run(() => SendMessageAsync(), task => 
{
   //We can have exception here if SendMessageAsync() fails
   var exception = task.InnerException.Exception;
   //Log the exception
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
```

Comment: `i need to return my client Ok() without waiting it to finish.` Your "client" doesn't need to await this function.

Comment: Hint: use `BackgroundWorker` and pass the `Task` into it for completion.

Comment: I guess it is kind of an asp.net core project? Add the tag which describes it

Comment: Hint: Please **do not** use `BackgroundWorker` - read https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html

Comment: Why do you `await` then? Run and forget - `SendMessageAsync("test");` - and return `return Task.FromResult<MyClass>(Ok);`

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html (hint: is a really bad idea - how to do better)

Comment: @SirRufo That article is from 2013 and refers to `System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker` (which is awful, we know) - I misspoke: I **meant** to say [`BackgroundService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: @Dai I know exactly from what time the article is and what it refers to. But it is very difficult for me to know that you meant BackgroundService when you write BackgroundWorker. I will try do make a better brain read in the future ;o)

Comment: Jack posting an answer as part of the question is frowned upon here. You are more than welcome to post your answer as a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias is it? I didn't know. Thank you sir. I will do it like you say from now on.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [basic distributed architecture](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html), as described on my blog. In summary:

1. A durable queue. Serialize the work to be done into this queue (e.g., `{ "operation" = "SendMessage", "data" = "test" }`).
2. A separate backend processor that reads from that queue and does the actual work (e.g., `SendMessageAsync(message.data)`).

Your backend processor can `await` the call to `SendMessageAsync` and then do further processing.

Comment: Acutally I need response just beacuse i wanted to know if message sent or not. Eventually only thing makes me afraid that what if an error occurs in `SendMessageAsync()`.
I fixed that with an owerload of `Task.Run()`. At least i can log the error. So fire and forget is enough for now.  As you said we need to read to queue if we want to see response. Maybe it would be overcomitting if I write a processor just for this. I am happy to found your blog, thanks Stephen.

Answer (score -1):

you should use as follows:

```
     await task1;

     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("task1 has been done");

     var task2 = Task.Run(async () =>
     {
         await Task.Delay(10000);
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("task2 has been done");
     });


      _ = Task.Run(() => task2);
```

According to the above codes, task 1 has been done without any delay and the request is finished based on the processing time of task 1, but task 2 has been done after ten seconds given that the request has been completed before. I hope these codes help you